# Does Spring has something like Play #{extends}?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, playframework

#{extends} is very helpful and easy to use in Play framework to extend layouts and manage layouts in views, but I'm wondering if Spring also has something similar to this?

I'd really appreciate if anyone has same kind of code for Spring.

In following Play example I am extending main.html by index.html which means index.html will use main.html as its layout:

```
/* views/main.html : */
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <div id="content">
        #{doLayout/}
        </div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>


/* views/Application/index.html : */
#{extends "main.html"/}
<h1>Home</h1>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Velocity, read http://sebastienayotte.wordpress.com/2009/03/20/using-velocity-layout-in-spring/

If you use freemarker, see http://richardbarabe.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/freemarker-a-brief-example/

If you want the behaviour exactly like play's groovy template, you can try [Rythm template engine](https://github.com/greenlaw110/rythm), read [this](http://software-lgl.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/rythm-easy-to-use-high-performance-java.html) and [this](http://software-lgl.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/step-by-step-migrate-your-groovy_24.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would like to try Rythm template engine but don't know how to use it with Spring, I guess I'm missing some steps. I only added the library and calling the Rythm.render in my Controller?

Comment: Goto https://github.com/greenlaw110/Rythm/downloads, choose the latest distribution pack. After download it you will be able to find samples folder. Go to that folder and type "ant" you should be able to see the sample execution result. Now read the build file and the sample code to understand the whole process. I think the biggest challenge is to configure the template root in your servlet environment. If you failed to configure that Rythm will try load templates from your class path root. After I released Play-rythm 1.0 I will come to traditional java world to work on samples and docs

Comment: Thanks again, is it possible to use Rythm as a Spring ViewResolver?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about Sprint. But all in all, you can use Rythm as a general java library. Just call new RythmEngine().render("template", args)

Comment: Hi monshi, checkout the sprint-rythm-template project at https://github.com/lawrence0819/spring-web-rythm-template. It might be helpful to you